# How to get a JSF2 table to be updated from time to time?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a page that enables the user to start a proccess that should update a table on this page from time to time. It already loads the data on the page, but I want the page to update itself alone on a given interval. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: I actually forgot saying I am using richfaces 4. I know richfaces3 had the a4j:pool, but I couldnt find it on rf4.

Answer (score 1):

Most JSF2 component libraries offer a Poll component, which refreshes the page or selected parts of it in regular intervals.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/ajaxPollHome.jsf

http://composite-component-showcase.icefaces.org/ee-composite-showcase/showcase.jsf

..etc.

AFAIK JSF2 has no built-in poll component. If you still want to stick to raw JSF2 then have a look at this article, to see how to implement one (it's not hard):

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/07/a_tale_of_two_c.html

But why sweat with bare JSF2 when you have excellent component libraries at your disposal?

Answer (score 0):

[a4j:poll](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_poll.html)